# On JQuery UI do one draggable connectToSortable multiple sortables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

In JQuery UI, I have a draggable, It have an option connectToSortable as below:

```
$("#social li").draggable({
       connectToSortable: '#form_builder_sortable',
       helper:'clone',
       revert:true
 });
```

'#form_builder_sortable' is a sortable as below:

```
$("#form_builder_sortable").sortable();
```

I want 1 draggable list connect to multiple sortable list, such as:

```
$("#social li").draggable(
{
    connectToSortable: '#form_builder_sortable, #form_builder_sortable_sample',
       helper:'clone',
       revert:true
 });
```

Have you got any solutions or suggestion to do as my requirement? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connectToSortable` option accepts a selector and a selector can specify any number of lists.

Please see following example:

**Draggable list**

```
<ul>
    <li class="draggable ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
</ul>
```

**Mulitiple list**

```
<ul id="form_builder_sortable" class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="form_builder_sortable_sample" class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I gave them same class `class="sortable"` because I want drag draggable list to both of them. Finally I can use code below for drag it:

```
$(".sortable").sortable();

$(".draggable").draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortable', // Selector selects lists that have sortable class
  helper: 'clone'
});
```

[**Online demo (fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/rLscuub5/)

Comment: It worked on Jquery 2.0 and Jquery UI 1.10.3 but It doesn't work for my current project using Jquery 1.7.2 and JQuery UI 1.8.9. Anyhow, Thank your help.