# how to make all the li components sortable for each ul parent?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a `div` that is appended every time a `button` is clicked. And each `div` has a `textbox` and a `button`. When the button is clicked, the value fetched from the `textbox` is appended to the parent(`ul`) as `li` components.

The `li` components should be sortable as I have made its `ul` sortable. The `li` are not sortable.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruju/nx4mrxko/)

Even though i have added sortable in this. The li components are not sortable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the code below, after `$('#selected'+c).append('<li id="add-card">' + value +'</li>');` like my online demo:

```
$('#selected'+c).sortable();
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/uL5nnuru/)

Comment: thank u :) but when i have another div with li as well.. Why cant i get them to be sortable. What i mean is `li` from div2 `ul` should drop to div1 `ul` since both of them have `consort` class. Because when i had used `sortable` before `li` from any div could be `dragged/dropped`. How can i achieve this?

Comment: what i mean in the previous question is how do i make any one of the `div's ul` `connectWith`  multiple `divs` considering that all the `ul` have the same class...`consort`

Comment: @sanjana I think following link helps you about `connectWith`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590926/on-jquery-ui-do-one-draggable-connecttosortable-multiple-sortables

Comment: @sanjana Please up-vote my answer for knowing and helping other people that it helps you because some people only see the up-voted answers.